# java didn't launch

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk

I just deleted the 10 version folder of openjdk.

```
rm -R jvm
```

I re-downloaded then jdk 8 , recreated  the folder jvm and extracted the jdk on it.

now my java-home points to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/` ,however when i run `java -version` i get this return :

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

what is wrong ?

**Edit**: the output of `update-java-alternatives -l` is :

```
awk: cannot open /usr/lib/jvm/*.jinfo (No such file or directory)
java-8-openjdk-amd64                      /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Please add output of `update-java-alternatives -l` to the question.

Comment: i have just update my question

Comment: You should decide which Java version you want to use and install it with package manager with `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless` or `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless`. Do not extract anything to folders, maintained by package manager!

Comment: they dosne't work i tried them

Comment: Try to set 8 version as default: `update-java-alternatives -s java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

Comment: when i try that i get  this :

update-java-alternatives: file does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/.java-8-openjdk-amd64.jinfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved my problem by reading [these](http://www.devsniper.com/install-jdk-8-on-ubuntu/)

i run those commands *(Install new java source in system)*:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac 1
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java 1
```

then those commands *(Choose default java:)*:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config javac
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try defining it without the jre on the end -

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181

tell me if it works.

Comment: If it doesnt work, try to run "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/.../jdk1.8.0_181" on the command line

Comment: i tried that, it dosen't work.
for the export JAVA_HOME it exists on /etc/environment it tried it on command line as well as you suggested that dosen't change anything

Comment: Did you try the suggestion to install java by the commands on the error?

Comment: yes they dosen't work too

Comment: Can you also add (beside the exported JAVA_HOME): 

> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin